# Is it correct to say "Do you have facebook?"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I often see people using "Are you on facebook?", but in Portuguese, for example, we say "Você tem facebook", which literally translated to english would be "Do you have facebook?".
Both "Are you on facebook?" and "Do you have facebook?" translated to portuguese is okay.
But what about in english?

Comment: This could help http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72008/can-i-say-do-you-have-a-facebook

Comment: Related question: [(In, On or At) GitHub?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/89101)

Answer (score 2):

Both are used in English, I prefer "Do you have facebook" or "Do you use facebook"

The second one is good as many people have but do not use facebook

"Are you on facebook" Is used but could be misunderstood as you asking if they are currently using facebook

Comment: I usually say "Are you on Facebook?", because if I'm talking to somebody, it's usually pretty apparent that they're not using Facebook right at that very moment, and just from context, there's little reason I would be asking if somebody was using Facebook at that very moment.  If I really needed to ask that, I'd probably add "...right now?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

> Do you have Facebook?

is fine.

What it means is

> Do you have Facebook among whatever social media or other online accounts you might use?

*Facebook* would be short for *Facebook access/accessibility*, which is basically  *a Facebook account*.

The same could be used for Twitter:

> Do you have Twitter?