# "posted to", "posted at", "posted on"

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should we use with *posted*?

> - A new question is **posted to** Stack Overflow every 12 seconds.
> - A new question is **posted at** Stack Overflow every 12 seconds.
> - A new question is **posted on** Stack Overflow every 12 seconds.

Some examples from news websites:

> The Supreme Court in Brisbane heard Lorang-Goubran met Mr Spencer through an online sex ad **posted to** website Craigslist and planned to rob him of drugs with a male accomplice. [ABC News](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-08-16/gold-coast-sex-worker-craigslist-mark-spencer-lorang-goubran/7747826)
>
> In one photograph **posted on** the website, Mr. Roof is shown posing with wax figures of slaves. [The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/21/us/dylann-storm-roof-photos-website-charleston-church-shooting.html)
>
> Notice of such cancellation, modification, or suspension will be **posted at** Website. [NBC Connecticut](http://www.nbcconnecticut.com/on-air/contests/New-England-Black-Wolves-Ticket-and-Overnight-Stay-Giveaway-411675275.html)

[Google books - Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=posted%20on%2C%20posted%20to%2C%20posted%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

[image]

[Google Tend](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=posted%20on,posted%20to,posted%20at):

[image]

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website)

Comment: Since you can find examples from all three on news sites (which presumably use "correct" English), all three are acceptable.  I'm not sure what your question is asking.

Comment: Which one is more common? which one you would use naturally?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [(In, On or At) GitHub?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/in-on-or-at-github/89103#89103)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following statements can be used interchangeably when you want to express Stack Overflow as an address where some post can be posted.

A new question is **posted to** Stack Overflow every 12 seconds.
A new question is **posted at** Stack Overflow every 12 seconds.

The following syntax expresses it in more specific way using "on", i.e. where a post was posted: e.g.  "**on** StackOverFlow page. or **on** a Facebook wall.