# in computer vs on computer

Tags: prepositions

Let's say that I have two workstations, "lengo1" and "lengo2". I would like to ask someone to transfer data from lengo1 to a folder "in?" or "on?" lengo2. For example:

> Would you mind transferring the data to my folder in lengo2?
>
> Would you mind transferring the data to my folder on lengo2?

In regard to preposition usage, which sentence is correct?

Comment: Would you mind transferring. The verb mind calls for using ing in the verb that follows it. Would you mind correcting your examples?

Comment: @Lambie. Thank you so much for correcting me. Would you mind answering my question: If I say "would you mind if you transfer the data to my folder in leng2" is this sentence sound correct?

Comment: @goro, that is not correct. "Would you please transfer the data..." would be good if you're trying to avoid the "ing" on transferring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(In, On or At) GitHub?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/in-on-or-at-github)

Comment: @goro when writing I believe that may be a bit awkward, but if you were to speak that it would sound totally fine in my opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Would you mind transferring the data to my folder on lengo2?

Usually when referring to a file located on a PC, we use the word **on**, not **in**. I attribute this to the fact that the data is encoded onto the hard drive's platter, not in the platter, but other people may have less technical reasons.

Comment: I agree, but it would me: to the folder on my PC. Also, it would be useful to correct the grammar, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, sometimes there is a shared computer, and you have your own folder on that belongs only to you. Such is common with college workstations, where users usually have their own individual folder. In this case, you would say *transfer the data to my folder*.

Comment: I'll go beyond "usually" to say that as an IT person I literally _never_ say a file is "in" a computer.  It's always "on".

Comment: @MontyHarder I second that.  Hardware is _in_ a computer, files are _on_ a computer

Comment: I agree, but you never know when that one person will come along and provide a counter example, if you understand what I'm saying. @MontyHarder

Comment: @Element115 Of course, you say ***transfer x to my folder***. But data and folders are said to be on a PC. No one would say, in one, except a doc is in a file.  The info, data, files or folders are on my laptop, on my desktop, on my computer. Of course, hardware is in a computer. But beware, in distributed computing, stuff (data) is said to be "in the cloud". Not on it. [ha ha]. Next? :)

Comment: Also files are said to be _in_ folders or subdirectories, not on.

Comment: Counterexample here.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TV3Oncvz_cU

Comment: I'm pretty sure the use of "on" has nothing to do with hard drives. Programs have been _on_ TV and music _on_ the radio for decades, so the usage seems at least related.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: I'd have to rewatch in context, but at a glance, I'd say that character is not a savvy user.

Comment: Indeed. **On** a computer, a domain, a drive, or a network share. **In** a folder, a directory, or a zip/compressed file.