# "account to a website" vs. "account on a website"

Tags: prepositions

> To use Gmail, I need to create **an account __ ** Google first and then I can sign in.

In the description above, should I use the preposition "on", "to" or "for"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(In, On or At) GitHub?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89101/in-on-or-at-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You **write** an email TO someone
- You **send** an email TO the editor/author of a website.
- You **set up** an account WITH a company.
- You **create** a Stack Exchange account
  You **create** an account ON Stack Exchange
- You **work** FOR a company
- You **do** a task or job FOR someone.

Therefore, the OP should use the preposition *on* in the blank

> To use Gmail, I need to **create** an account **ON** Google first and then I can sign in.

From *[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts)*

> *To create **an account on** Stack Overflow, please sign up through Google, Facebook, or create a new Stack Exchange account using an email address and password.*
>
> *In addition **to creating an account for this site** (and its associated meta-discussion site), you will also have a Stack Exchange network profile, which is accessible from your user page on any site where you have an account. This means that if you create **an account on** any other Stack Exchange site, it will be linked to your account here.*